# Terminal MacOS emoji support

Tags: shell, vim, utf-8, zsh, emoji

I was just wondering if anyone knows the emoji support that the Terminal.app has in MacOS?
I'm using zsh, and I end up with this when I type it out, I get the following (note I didn't add a space after the flag on the first one, but added a space on the second one but in both cases you can see there's an overlap on the flag, also note the duplication on the spaces and f on the end of the input)

[image: Terminal input]

And when using vim I also get

[image: Vim input]

Just wondering how people resolve these?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming but about configuring OS tools (also not related to programming). I recommend to migrate the question to https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It’s basically a multibyte rendering issue